# Is there a Tufte box set?

Tags: data-visualization, references

Apologies in advance that this is probably off topic and minutes away from being closed, but I couldn't think where else to ask and I hope you guys can help.

I'd like to get hold of Edward Tufte's books on Data Visualisation. Is there a nice box set I can buy? If not is there a definitive list of "The Tufte books" that I should buy?

Comment: I don't know if there's a box set. Why not check on Amazon? I think the publisher & Tufte himself both have websites as well.

Comment: Which of Tufte's books you should get strikes me as on topic, but you'll need to be more specific about what you need. Otherwise, why wouldn't the answer just be 'all of them'? After all, there aren't that many & they aren't that hard to read. I've read them all, & I'd bet many of the contributors here have, too.

Comment: Note that Tufte wrote various books before he started writing on graphics.   This is prominently documented. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte although his own website appears to imply otherwise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte

Answer (score 2):

When you do the [one-day workshop](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/courses), you get these four in a nice box:

- Visual Explanations
- Envisioning Information
- The Visual Display of Quantitative Information
- Beautiful Evidence.